# Pandas utf-8 error in opening a csv file from Meta?

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

So, I just downloaded some audience data from Meta as a csv file and I was hoping to create a panda data frame so that I could do some analysis. After importing Pandas and trying to read the csv file I get the following error:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte'

So, I assume there's something wrong with the file. However, when I open the csv file with Pages on Mac, it looks like a regular database. I don't understand what is wrong and how to eventually surpass the problem. I am still a bit of a beginner so any help would be appreciated

I was expecting a simple database, I got an error I've never seen before. I never encountered utf-8 errors

Comment: Are you sure this is  UTF8? 0xFF FE is a common way to begin UTF16 files.

Comment: All text files have an encoding and in your case it isn't the default used by `read_csv`.  Read [the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and specify the `encoding` parameter to `pandas.read_csv()` correctly.

Answer (score -1):

you can pass an encoding option to your read_csv command as follow:

```
df= pd.read_csv('Region_count.csv', encoding ='latin1')
```

if it didn't work use some other common encodings like:

```
encoding = "cp1252"
encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
encoding = "utf-8"
```